# Measuring how long it took for a user to download an image with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to measure how long it took for a client to download an image from my node server.

I tried in different methods, none gave me an accurate answer.
the callback of res.sendFile seems to work on the 'finish' event and it indicates when the data was passed to the operating system fully (and not the client).
I tried to divide the image into smaller chunks and writing to the response, I tried the events of the socket, also with no success - at first the 'close' event seemed good (res.socket.on('close',)) on my local machine, but then it didn't work as expected on a remote machine.

isn't there something that can indicate that the client received the whole image? a FIN packet or something?

I am also open for solutions in different languages, doesnt matter.
Tried to investigate the matter with python and php, but didnt find a straightforward solution.

thanks :)

Comment: Even if it were easy to catch FIN packets, you'd run into the problem of HTTP keep-alive or HTTP/2 multiplexing, where a connection may not get closed by the client directly after received one full response. The most accurate method would be to measure this client-side, but I assume that's not possible?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do it in an email, which cant use javascript